# Como ordenar los valores en un diccionario de python

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios, ordenamiento

tengo un problema con el desarrollo de un algoritmo de ordenamiento de diccionarios en python. Se me da un diccionario y se me pide que, mediante merge sort(no esta permitido usar built-in functions) ordene este diccionario de tal manera que el value vaya en orden ascendete. Todo esto debe lograrse en aproximadamente 1 segundo, me dicen que el problema esta en doble loop for del final, que eso es lo que causa la demora. como puedo solucionar ese inconveniente del doble loop for? aqui esta la parte importante del codigo:

```
    def orden(lista):
        if len(lista) > 1:
            mid = len(lista) // 2
            lefthalf = lista[:mid]
            righthalf = lista[mid:]

            orden(lefthalf)
            orden(righthalf)

            i = 0
            j = 0
            k = 0
            while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
                if lefthalf[i] <= righthalf[j]:
                    lista[k] = lefthalf[i]
                    i = i + 1
                else:
                    lista[k] = righthalf[j]
                    j = j + 1
                k = k + 1

            while i < len(lefthalf):
                lista[k] = lefthalf[i]
                i = i + 1
                k = k + 1

            while j < len(righthalf):
                lista[k] = righthalf[j]
                j = j + 1
                k = k + 1
        return lista

    lista = list(self.futbol.values())

    orden(lista)
    diccionario = {}

    for i in lista:
       for j in self.futbol.keys():
           if self.futbol[j] == i:
               diccionario[j] = self.futbol[j]
               break
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar lo que hay en el diccionario `self.futbol` para tener un conjunto de datos de ejemplo con los que hacer pruebas? Si es muy largo basta que muestres solo algunas entradas del diccionario.

Answer (score 1):

## Aviso

Lo primero comentar un defecto del propio enunciado del problema, y es el concepto de "ordenar un diccionario". Los diccionarios no tienen orden interno, por lo que dependiendo de la versión de python que uses es posible que, pese a todo el trabajo que te tomas en ordenar el diccionario, al llegar al final e imprimir el resultado lo veas "desordenado", ya que en versiones anteriores a Python 3.7 los diccionarios **no garantizaban el orden de inserción**.

Esto quiere decir que aunque tú primero hagas `diccionario["a"] = 1` y después `diccionario["b"] = 0`, cuando muestres el diccionario perfectamente podrías encontrarte `{'b': 0, 'a': 1}` en vez de `{'a': 1, 'b': 0}` como podrías esperar. Y lo mismo si iteras por el diccionario, `diccionario.items()` puede retornarte las claves en cualquier orden impredecible.

Esto cambió en Python 3.7 y ahora, a partir de esa versión, sí se garantiza el orden de inserción. Es decir, que las claves serán retornadas en el mismo orden en que fueron insertadas en el diccionario.

## Solución

Dicho lo anterior, y suponiendo que trabajas con Python 3.7 o superior, sí sería posible crear un diccionario "ordenado" en el sentido en que se pide en el enunciado.

La solución puede ser muy simple si te das cuenta de que la función `orden()` que has programado funciona para cualquier lista que le pases, sea cual sea el contenido de esa lista, con tal de que los elementos de la misma se puedan comparar entre sí. Lo mismo te sirve para ordenar listas de números (que es para lo que la has usado), que listas de cadenas, por ejemplo, ya que las cadenas también se pueden comparar entre sí, y toda la clave de la ordenación descansa en la comparación `lefthalf[i] <= righthalf[j]` que simplemente compara dos elementos de la lista.

En particular, también funciona para ordenar **listas de tuplas**. Si la lista que le pasas en vez de contener números contiene parejas de datos, se ordenará correctamente porque python permite comparar una tupla con otra. Por ejemplo, esta comparación sería cierta:

```
  (1, "Pepe") <= (3, "Juan")
```

Pues para comparar tuplas python compara antes sus primeros elementos y en este caso es cierto que `1 <= 3`.

Gracias a esto puedes construir una lista que, en vez de tener los valores del diccionario `futbol`, tenga parejas `(valor, clave)`. La lista quedará ordenada por valores, pero cada valor llevará asociada una clave, que permitirá reconstruir el diccionario.

Tal lista puedes obtenerla así:

```
lista = [ (valor, clave) for clave, valor in self.futbol.items() ]
```

Después se la pasas a tu función:

```
orden(lista)
```

Y tu función te ordenará las tuplas por su primer elemento, es decir, por los valores del diccionario original. En base a esta lista puedes construir el diccionario ordenado:

```
diccionario = { clave: valor for valor, clave in lista }
```

Si no conoces esta sintaxis (comprensión de diccionarios) puedes hacer un bucle normal:

```
diccionario = {}
for valor, clave in lista:
  diccionario[clave] = valor
```